# Transiting US with Canadian and other citizenship

Tags: visas

I am a Canadian citizen with a valid Canadian passport, and my son is Mexican but he has his Canadian citizenship and Canadian passport.  Do we need some sort of special permission if I want to travel to Canada with a connecting flight through the United States?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. If you child has Canadian citizenship and a Canadian passport, he is Canadian, not Mexican, so it's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Separately, is your son a child or an adult?

Comment: @choster it's of course also possible that the son is both Canadian *and* Mexican.

Answer (score 5):

You and your son both carry Canadian passports. Unless there is some unfavorable circumstance such as a criminal record, Canadians do not need a visa for transit through the US (or indeed for most other purposes).  As long as the traveler presents a Canadian passport, it does not matter what other citizenship may be held or where the traveler was born.

Canadian citizens also have a right to enter Canada, of course.  Therefore, to answer your question:

> Do we need some sort of special permission if I want to travel to Canada with a connecting flight through the United States?

No.